# If I move my SQLdata file from my F drive, delete the F drive, and rename the new Drive F will I have any file path problems?

Tags: sql-server, partitioning

I have a windows server that only had 50 GB on the C drive and 4TB on the F drive. I need to exstend the C drive but the only way to do that is by deleting the F drive to reallocate space. If I move data from the F drive to a new drive, delete the F drive, and rename the new drive, will I loss the file path?

Comment: You could instead use a standard naming convention or maybe even `mount points` on a drive like Z. Then you have `Z:\Data\DISK1` instead of the F drive where you store the datafiles in a folder, like `Z:\Data\DISK1\sql_dat\myDB.mdf`. Either way, you will have to make sure SQL Server has access to the locations as the drive location does not share or have cascading permissions.

Answer (score 2):

> If I move data from the F drive to a new drive, delete the F drive,
>   and rename the new drive, will I loss the file path?

If you're going to move everything on F:\ to a new underlying disk and rename that disk F:\ then you should be okay, but you need to ensure all permissions are correctly migrated to avoid issues during restart.

The basic process would be:

1. Stop SQL Server
2. Copy all data from F:\ to new drive using robocopy or similar tool that can bring permissions as well.
3. Remount F:\ as a new drive letter
4. Remount new disk as F:\
5. Restart SQL Server and verify health

Reverting should be as simple as reversing the drive letter changes if you run into issues.